# How to apply a derived column list (table and column aliases) to a table valued function call in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alias, user-defined-functions

I'm emulating PostgreSQL style `generate_series()` table-valued functions in SQL Server as such:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_series(@d1 DATE, @d2 DATE)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
  -- Ignore implementation (returning a single DATE column) for this question
```

This can now be used as expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(
  CAST ('2005-07-01' AS DATE),
  CAST ('2005-07-31' AS DATE)
) t
```

Now I'd like to use derived column list syntax to rename columns along with the table as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(
  CAST ('2005-07-01' AS DATE),
  CAST ('2005-07-31' AS DATE)
) t(col)
```

Which is producing this error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 15, Line 5
>   'generate_series' is not a recognized function name.

... whereas this syntax (qualifying the function) ...

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.generate_series(
  CAST ('2005-07-01' AS DATE),
  CAST ('2005-07-31' AS DATE)
) t(col)
```

... is producing this error:

> Msg 317, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Table-valued function 'generate_series' cannot have a column alias.

This syntax is perfectly valid in my opinion. It works this way in PostgreSQL, standard SQL, and in "ordinary" T-SQL as well, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  VALUES (1),(2)
) t(col)
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I achieve this? ([I'm aware of the possibility of emulating this](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/01/07/simulating-the-sql-standard/), but I'd like to really use derived column list syntax).

I'm using SQL Server Express 2014

Comment: You need the schema / function owner in there.  Default being `dbo` would therefore give `FROM dbo.generate_series`

Comment: @MatBailie: Egh. Ok, thank you. But that doesn't solve the problem yet. Will update.

Comment: Given the nature of the error message 317, which seems oddly, shall we say, **specific**, I wouldn't expect to find a way to directly apply a column alias to a table-valued function.

Comment: The grammar is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx. `column_alias` can only be applied in a few cases. Not including `user_defined_function `

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks, that would be the ideal answer if you want to put that. Interestingly, column aliases are allowed with `@variable.function_call`...

Comment: yes. `declare @x xml
select foo.value('.','int') from @x.nodes('/') v(foo)` is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of the from clause is here.

`column_alias` is only supported for derived tables and `@variable.function_call`

```
[ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
<table_source> ::=   
{  
    table_or_view_name [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
        [ <tablesample_clause> ]   
        [ WITH ( < table_hint > [ [ , ]...n ] ) ]   
    | rowset_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
        [ ( bulk_column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]   
    | user_defined_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
    | OPENXML <openxml_clause>   
    | derived_table [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]   
    | <joined_table>   
    | <pivoted_table>   
    | <unpivoted_table>  
    | @variable [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
    | @variable.function_call ( expression [ ,...n ] )   
        [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]  
    | FOR SYSTEM_TIME <system_time>   
}
```

So, at least for the time being, you would need to wrap the `user_defined_function` call. e.g. in a derived table or CTE to alias the columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT *
       FROM dbo.generate_series(
        CAST ('2005-07-01' AS DATE),
        CAST ('2005-07-31' AS DATE)
    )) t(col)
```

I would guess it is because although dbo.generate_series is a function it is returning a table.  so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  TableName t(Col)
```

Wouldn't work

but

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT *
   FROM
     TableName t
) t(col)
```

Would work

So in other words Derived Columns list will work with a derived table but not when the table is NOT derived?

I would assume the preferred syntax which I am sure you know is to use column aliases rather than derived column list.

```
SELECT d as Col
FROM
    dbo.generate_series(
        CAST ('2005-07-01' AS DATE),
        CAST ('2005-07-31' AS DATE)
    ) t
```

Comment: Indeed, there are other workarounds too, as mentioned in [the article I've linked](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/01/07/simulating-the-sql-standard/), including CTE, UNION with a dummy first subquery...

Comment: @LukasEder I think mine an Sean's point is that the function is a table not a derived table so you cannot use a derived column list with it.  But I will admit I don't use derived column lists too much so I wouldn't consider myself a defacto voice on the subject.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't think that SQL Server uses the standard term "derived column list", but I guess that's still the best explanation (and PostgreSQL bends the standard to make this work in a broader context). Your first example is really the closest workaround for SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a column alias in this case. This is not using a table valued constructor, it is returning from a table valued function. Just drop the column alias and it is fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.generate_series(
  CAST ('2005-07-01' AS DATE),
  CAST ('2005-07-31' AS DATE)
) t
```

FWIW, I would suggest using a tally table instead of recursive cte in your function. If your date range is lengthy the performance is going to suffer because you are effectively using a rcte to count. If you examine the execution plan it is the same thing as a while loop. Jeff Moden has an awesome article discussing this in great detail. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

--EDIT--

To create an alias can you not simply add an alias?

```
SELECT t.d as MyAlias
FROM dbo.generate_series(
  CAST ('2005-07-01' AS DATE),
  CAST ('2005-07-31' AS DATE)
) t
```

Comment: Thanks, but you're not really answering my question :) 1) performance is off topic (I'll update my question), 2) syntax is the important part here (at least for me)

Comment: 1) performance should never be off topic. 2) I did answer your question. If you want to alias the column just add an alias in the select like you would for any other query.

Comment: 1) OK if you insist :). But it's noise in the context of my question, so let me just replace the implementation with a comment (removing my own noise). 2) The `SELECT` alias won't work in general, because that name is unavailable to all the other clauses (e.g. `WHERE`).

Comment: 1) that's why it is at the end of my post. And most people don't realize how horrible the performance of a counting cte can be. :) 2) it is true that you can't use it in a where clause but it was not clear in your question (at least to me) that you needed that. You would have to use a cte or subquery as Matt posted.